# Downloading Ubuntu to Mac for use on PC

Tags: downloads

Can I download Ubuntu on to a Mac, save it to a memory stick to install on a PC and leave the Mac untouched?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you download Ubuntu using web browser or torrent, you should get a file Ubuntu.iso or something like that (Ubuntu comes in .iso file, which can be directly burn to a CD using CD burning software).

All you need to do, after that, is to install pendrive Linux (not sure if it is available on Mac) and you can install the iso file to pendrive.

Comment: Have a look at the official guide. You have to convert the Ubuntu ISO to UDIF format, then you can simply `dd` it to the device node of your USB key.
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

I'm wondering, why one has to convert the ISO first, since for Debian ISO files this step is not necessary...

Comment: Well, what I can say is .iso is an image file, and that image file can be used widely (can burn to CD, run in virtual cd-rom, pendrive-linux) and is everything in a file (1 file with lots of files and folders in it), which is easily to transfer the file.